# How can I join two tables with one same field in common?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to join two tables that share one ID in common.

I would like to create this table:

ID - Year - Month - Cost

I have one table by year, how is the code to do that? I'm confused with join and select...

This is the example table:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKhRCALbxhbRXmVtBZac75sDlz5v-ykxcbYhgfZ4SHw/edit?usp=sharing

I have this code but I would like separate by year (2019, 2018) in one column and another column by month (1, 2, 3...).

I answer myself, I could do it with this code. I paste just in case someone need it.

```html
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Campaign_name,
  Year,
  Month,
  SUM(Cost) AS Cost
FROM (
  SELECT
    Campaign_name,
    Year,
    Month,
    Cost
  FROM
    `ucjc.google_ads_bruto_2019`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Campaign_name,
    Year,
    Month,
    Cost
  FROM
    `ucjc.google_ads_bruto_2018`)
GROUP BY
  Campaign_name,
  Year,
  Month
ORDER BY
  Campaign_name
```

thanks!

Comment: Please specify how your input tables look like.

Comment: i edit my message ;)

Comment: @nshabi could you please post your edit as an actual answer for the sake of the community? Thank you!

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa i added the actual answer in my first message, if i publish again, maybe i duplicate the answer, isn't it?

Comment: @nshabi, the ideal is to get a separated approved answer so it's is easy to read through the post for the next users :)"

Answer (score 1):

I copy the solution I found.

```html
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Campaign_name,
  Year,
  Month,
  SUM(Cost) AS Cost
FROM (
  SELECT
    Campaign_name,
    Year,
    Month,
    Cost
  FROM
    `ucjc.google_ads_bruto_2019`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Campaign_name,
    Year,
    Month,
    Cost
  FROM
    `ucjc.google_ads_bruto_2018`)
GROUP BY
  Campaign_name,
  Year,
  Month
ORDER BY
  Campaign_name
```